# Go through cells to find which one equals a value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have values in A1-A10, I know one of them will equal a specific value. What is the easiest way to determine which cell equals the specific value? I know I can do it with a nested if statement but is there an easier way to accomplish this task? Thank you!

Comment: .........................Use `MATCH()`

Answer (score 0):

To find *"gold"*:

```
="A" & MATCH("gold",A1:A10,0)
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

Here is an example of matching in one column and retrieving from another:

[image]

Comment: Thank you never used match before. Actually the values are in B3-B13 and I have a key beside it in A3-A13. How could I use match to instead of giving me the cell in B3-B13 to give me corresponding value beside it in A3-A13? Note I'll only have one instance of the value so I won't have to worry about multiple cells having the same value.

Comment: @user1620479 `INDEX(A:A,MATCH("gold",B:B,0))`

Comment: @user1620479  There are **2** approaches.  Either use a combination of `MATCH()` and `INDEX()` or use `VLOOKUP()`